# Jenkins : Build not failing even the code is incorrect syntax wise

Tags: jenkins

I missed one of the semicolon to see the red build on the jenkins, while using the Git

```
public class SpringbootController {
    public void callSerivce() {
        System.out.println("to check se changes");
        System.out.println("to check se changes")
    }
}
```

but still on the jenkins, it is showing the build is successful.

don't know what exactly i missed,please help

newbie in jenkins

is there anything i need to add in the shell to make it work, right now it is empty.

Comment: What does your job look like? Are you using a freestyle job or a pipelines job? What build steps are in your job?

Comment: it's free style

Comment: let me add the screenshot of that

Comment: it is empty , i didnt add any build steps, if you dont mind could you please provide some steps how to create those build steps

Comment: That'd explain it. Jenkins is checking out your code and then completing. So as long as the checkout succeeds it'll always pass. How do you build your project locally (e.g. ant, maven, gradle, ivy, etc)?

Comment: using maven, build my project

Comment: As long as you have the maven plugin installed (I think it's installed by default), add a build step of "Invoke top-level Maven Targets". I haven't used it in a while, but as long as your POM has appropriate defaults I think that's all you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, it is not installed by default.do u have any idea which one we need to install ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181773/discussion-between-michael-powers-and-sparsh610).

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the conversation in the comments: in order for Jenkins to build your code you need to tell it how to build your code. By default Jenkins doesn't do anything beyond the SCM checkout on its own.

Since you're building a Java project with Maven you should add a Maven build step after your SCM checkout. You will need the [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin).

In your post-build steps you should add an "Archive the artifacts" step to gather up anything built during your job you want to keep since your workspace will get potentially wiped out next run.